# How change selected value of radio buttons in R Shiny manually?

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button

I have an R Shiny UI component with radio buttons and would like to manually change the selected value from the code.

Let say, there are 3 values: "Stay here", "Do it", and "Go away". By selecting "Do it" the user sees the action button "Do it". I'd like to change the selected radio buttons value on "stay_here" after the user clicked on the action button "Do it". Here is the code.

```
library(shiny)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(uiOutput("rbtn_test")),
    fluidRow(uiOutput("uo_stay_here")),
    fluidRow(uiOutput("uo_do_it")),
    fluidRow(uiOutput("uo_go_away"))))

# SERVER
server <- function(input, output) {
   
   # 1. Radio buttons
   output$rbtn_test <- renderUI({
     
     # 1.1. Values
     actions_values <- c("stay_here", "do_it", "go_away")
     names(actions_values) <- c("Stay here", "Do it", "Go away")
     
     # 1.2. Selected value
     action_selected <- "stay_here"
     
     # 1.3. UI element
     radioButtons(
       "rbtn_test_selected", "Actions", 
       choices = actions_values, 
       selected = action_selected, 
       inline = TRUE)
   })
   
   # 2. 'Stay here'
   output$uo_stay_here <- renderUI({
     if(input$rbtn_test_selected == "stay_here") {
       tags$div(tags$p("Stay here ..."))
     }
   })
   
   # 3. Process 'Do it' action
   output$uo_do_it <- renderUI({
     
     if(input$rbtn_test_selected == "do_it") {
       actionButton("btn_doit", "Do it")
       # TBD: Change selected value in radio buttons on 'stay_here'
     }
     
   })
   
   # 4. 'Go away'
   output$uo_go_away <- renderUI({
     if(input$rbtn_test_selected == "go_away") {
       tags$div(tags$p("Go away ..."))
     }
   })
   
   
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an `observeEvent` on "Do it" action button which will change the selected value on click.

```
 observeEvent(input$btn_doit, {
    updateRadioButtons(session, "rbtn_test_selected", selected = "stay_here")
  })
```

Complete code -

```
library(shiny)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(uiOutput("rbtn_test")),
    fluidRow(uiOutput("uo_stay_here")),
    fluidRow(uiOutput("uo_do_it")),
    fluidRow(uiOutput("uo_go_away"))))

# SERVER
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # 1. Radio buttons
  output$rbtn_test <- renderUI({
    
    # 1.1. Values
    actions_values <- c("stay_here", "do_it", "go_away")
    names(actions_values) <- c("Stay here", "Do it", "Go away")
    
    # 1.2. Selected value
    action_selected <- "stay_here"
    
    # 1.3. UI element
    radioButtons(
      "rbtn_test_selected", "Actions", 
      choices = actions_values, 
      selected = action_selected, 
      inline = TRUE)
  })
  
  # 2. 'Stay here'
  output$uo_stay_here <- renderUI({
    if(input$rbtn_test_selected == "stay_here") {
      tags$div(tags$p("Stay here ..."))
    }
  })
  
  # 3. Process 'Do it' action
  output$uo_do_it <- renderUI({
    
    if(input$rbtn_test_selected == "do_it") {
      actionButton("btn_doit", "Do it")
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$btn_doit, {
    updateRadioButtons(session, "rbtn_test_selected", selected = "stay_here")
  })
  
  # 4. 'Go away'
  output$uo_go_away <- renderUI({
    if(input$rbtn_test_selected == "go_away") {
      tags$div(tags$p("Go away ..."))
    }
  })
  
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this sophisticated answer!